# How to upload a file in Selenium when sendKeys is not working

Tags: javascript, java, selenium

The HTML code is of type shadow DOM.

This is the input type:

```
<input hidden type="file" id="fileInput" accept=".doc,.docx,.pdf,.jpg,.png">
```

[image: console screenshot]

Comment: which language are you working Python or Java? You need to mentioned?

Comment: Hi! How is going? Did you try my answer? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can try make this element not hidden, by executing a JavaScript script, using JavaScriptExecutor, which is in Selenium. I made this kind of thing in my project, because in IE SendKeys also didn't work for hidden input.

Answer (score 0):

You need to make input visible, using JS. The full steps are described below:

```
// Find file input element
WebElement input = driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("input[type='file']"));

// Make sure element is visible
((JavascriptExecutor) driver).executeScript("arguments[0].style.display = 'block';", input);

// Specify you local file path here
input.sendKeys("/path/to/file/on/machine/which/runs/tests");
```

In case of RemoteDriver do not forget add this:

```
// Configure your client to upload local files to remote Selenium instance
    driver.setFileDetector(new LocalFileDetector());
```

NOTE: filepath should be absolute. You may make it in this way:

```
String getFilePath(String filePath) {
    new File(filePath).absolutePath
}
```

Answer (score 0):

if the type file is in the shadowroot, you currently can't access it with selenium.

This has nothing to do with the field being invisible

Usually, you could do something like this:

```
$el = $driver->findElement(\WebDriverBy::xpath('//*[@type="file"]')
$el->setFileDetector(new \LocalFileDetector());
$el->sendKeys($imagepath);

// or mink:
$el = $driver->getPage()->find('xpath', '//*[@type="file"]');
$el->attachFile($path);
```

But, if its in the shadow-root, using this in the console wont find it:

```
$x('//*[@type="file"]')
```

and neither will this:

```
$("input[type='file']")
```

You can inspect and right click the input element and get element by js, and you will probably get an element path like this

```
document.querySelector("body > something").shadowRoot.querySelector("div > div > something").shadowRoot.querySelector("#someid")
```

This means it can only be accessed via shadow roots, and can be done with the above javascript

Selenium Javascript can not return the element (but selenium can do the upload as shown above if it could get the element)
Javascript will not allow you to upload since it would be insecure (but you can get the element in js from the above)

But the problem is, you cant return the javascript element as a php selenium element.  So there is no way for 2 to work together.

The real issue is, selenium does not yet support shadow roots